# Array for QImage crashs at first index and isint initialized with 0 at other?

Tags: qt, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays, qimage, qpixmap

I have a 3D-Array (first index for buffer) for representing as image and allocate memory for it. Afterwards I initialize it with 0. But when I try to save my array in a QImage and then make a Pixmap out of the Image, my program crashes at the very first bufferIndex and is not black at the other bufferIndexes (but has some stripes). What is my problem? Thank you!

```
#define BUFFERSIZE 8

#define SCENEHEIGHT 1024
#define SCENEWIDTH 1024

quint8 ***ringBuffer;

//allocating memory for videoBuffer
ringBuffer=(quint8 ***) malloc(BUFFERSIZE * sizeof(quint8 **));
for(int i=0;i<BUFFERSIZE;i++)
{
    ringBuffer[i]=(quint8 **)malloc(SCENEHEIGHT * sizeof(quint8 *));
    for(int y=0;y<SCENEHEIGHT;y++)
        ringBuffer[i][y]=(quint8 *)malloc(SCENEWIDTH * sizeof(quint8));
}

//initializing videoBuffer
bufferIndex = 0;
for(int i=0;i<BUFFERSIZE;i++)
    for(int y=0;y<SCENEWIDTH;y++)
        for(int x=0;x<SCENEHEIGHT;x++)
            ringBuffer[i][y][x]=0;

videoImage = new QImage(*(videoUDPSocketThread->videoSocket->ringBuffer[bufferIndex]), 
    /*crash at bufferIndex=0, no full black Image at bufferIndex= 1 to 7*/
    SCENEWIDTH, SCENEHEIGHT, QImage::Format_Indexed8);

videoImage->setColorCount(256);
for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    videoImage->setColor(i, qRgb(i, 0, 0));

QPixmap::fromImage(*videoImage); //<-- crash at this point

//videoPixmap = ppiScene->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(*videoImage));
```

### Edit, new Code

videoudpsocket.h

```
typedef QVector<QImage> RingBuffer;

class VideoUDPSocket : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    quint8 bufferIndex;

    RingBuffer ringBuffer;

private:

    RingBuffer newBuffer();
    QImage newImage();

signals:
    void videoRead(int bufferIndex);
};

#endif // VIDEOUDPSOCKET_H
```

videoudpsocket.cpp

```
VideoUDPSocket::VideoUDPSocket(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{
    ringBuffer = newBuffer();
    bufferIndex = 0;
}

QImage VideoUDPSocket::newImage() {
  QImage image = QImage(SCENEWIDTH, SCENEHEIGHT, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
  image.setColorCount(256);
  for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    image.setColor(i, qRgb(i, 0, 0));
  return image;
}

RingBuffer VideoUDPSocket::newBuffer() {

  RingBuffer buffer;
  buffer.reserve(BUFFERSIZE);
  for (int i = 0; i < BUFFERSIZE; ++i)
    buffer.push_back(newImage());
  return buffer;
}
```

getting and setting Vektor-Data:

```
ringBuffer.data()[bufferIndex].setPixel(x, y, max(signal%256, ringBuffer.data()[bufferIndex].pixelIndex(x,y)));
```

### EDIT2, adding more information

The purpose of this code is to get radar-video-data via UDP-Socket (I think about 22MB per second), convert the data from polar coordinates to cartesian, including offset and scalefactor to create a radar-video of 1024x1024 pixels. I think I need to calculate offset and scalefactor to save the data directly to a 1024x1024 Image because otherwise i would need an array of about 256 MB per radar-video-image. For now I know my algorithm is way too slow for that and I need to improve that.

Comment: Do not use the preprocessor to set constants. Do not use magic constants (like 256). The use of `setPixel` and `pixelIndex` is expensive if you're setting the pixels in a loop: show us that loop! It's also not clear whether you need the ring buffer. Edit the question to explain what is the purpose of the buffer. The `newImage` and `newBuffer` are free functions, not methods. Don't promote free functions to methods unnecessarily.

Comment: I added the informations you asked for. What do you mean by free functions and methods? And why should i not use the constants like that?
If setting and getting pixels like that is expensive that would be a big problem since my code will need to be mostly real time...

Comment: Free function is a function that doesn't belong in a class. `newBuffer` and `newImage` are such functions. `setPixel` and `pixelIndex` should be replaced with direct access to the data of `QImage`: that's the fast and direct way to manipulate the pixels.

Comment: For radar data rendering, setting pixels one-by-one is a lost cause. To get something that looks decent, you'd maintain a mesh with nodes at polar coordinates, update the mesh with intensities coming over UDP, and then render the mesh by interpolating between the nodes using some kernel. This rendering can be done on the CPU in a parallel fashion - it scales very nicely. It can also be done on the GPU. The rendering on the CPU would be done in linear stripes that have nothing to do with any radar scan patterns anymore. The mesh's purpose is to precondition the data for fast rendering.

Comment: The big question is: does the radar data always include the same set of polar coordinates, or do they vary between frames? If they vary, are they unpredictable, or are they simply a choice from a predetermined set (say 4 sets of coordinates that the data steps through).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An image is a contiguous array of bytes. You can't be allocating each line separately - it must all come in one block.

You're also unnecessarily writing C code in a C++ world. Use containers - that's what they are for. Finally, a `QImage` is already a container - there's no point to allocating memory for its buffer manually.

```
typedef QVector<QImage> RingBuffer;

QImage newImage() {
  const QSize kSceneSize { 1024, 1024 };
  const auto  kSceneFormat { QImage::Format_Indexed8 };
  const auto  kColorCount { 256 };

  QImage image { kSceneSize, kSceneFormat };
  image.setColorCount(kColorCount);
  for (int i = 0; i < kColorCount; ++i)
    image.setColor(i, qRgb(i, 0, 0));
  return image;
}

RingBuffer newBuffer() {
  const auto kBufferSize { 8 };

  RingBuffer buffer;
  buffer.reserve(kBufferSize);
  for (int i = 0; i < kBufferSize; ++i)
    buffer.push_back(newImage());
  return buffer;
}

class MyClass : ... {
  RingBuffer m_ring { newBuffer() };
  ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I have some problems understanding your code:
I get a error for the `RingBuffer m_ring { newBuffer() };` line: `Illegal definition of local function` What does this line do? How can I resolve this error and make m_ring public? Also I do not really get, what `newBuffer()`is doing... Is it first reserving memory with `buffer.reserve()` and than adding QImages to the vector with `push_back()`? And how can I access every single QImage (for getting and setting pixels)? Thank you!

Comment: I think I got it now (see edited code). Well at least my program is showing something that could be right and updating through the buffer without showing any errors. Thank you very much! If you just could do me a favor and check my new code, whether i can improve it (or it is still wrong)?